# Server transfer and bandwidth

Tags: transfer, bandwidth

My host server provide 1TB transfer and 1Gbps bandwith. Does it mean that if I transfer data for 10 seconds at max bandwidth I have transferred 10Gb ?

Comment: `1 Gbps` is `1 Gigabit per second`. In 10 seconds you will transfer `10 Gigabits`. It's `1.25 Gb`

Comment: Yes you are right. I was doing this calculation to understand if it is possible to develop an audio streaming service on this host.